# Node/Twilio Browser/SMS chat?

Tags: node.js, sms, twilio

Is there any project out there that uses twillio and node to let phones chat with a client in the browser? or forwards SMS messages to xmpp and then forwards xmpp back to twilio? I've been looking for an hour or so and I can't seem to find a project that does this. I've found some services that would let me build it, but I'd rather not recreate the wheel here.

Comment: Not with twilio, but I did it with raw FreeSWITCH :D [node-esl](https://github.com/englercj/node-esl)

Comment: Does it have to be Twilio, or are you just suggesting that as a possible SMS back-end?

Comment: Similarly, does it have to be node.js, or are you just suggesting that as a possible platform?

Comment: Ideally Twilio for me because it fits into my personal big picture. But, I'd be open to looking at solutions that use other tech. I'm not attached to node, but the persistant connections made me think it was ideal... I suppose if it were using xmpp I could just use a chat client instead of the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, don't know of anything out of the box, but that would make a good open source hack for our dev blog. If you're looking at using Twilio with node, you might want to check out my client module on npm.  If you want to play with it:

`npm install twilio`

Source:

https://github.com/kwhinnery/twilio-node

**EDIT:** You might check out this example app as well for Google App Engine:

https://github.com/kwhinnery/gae-chat

Comment: Thanks. I'll let you know if I hack anything together. If no one else responds, I'll give the answer to you.